# what is the source suggesting that blasphemous sentences are exempted in distressing situations?

Tags: petur-exemption, curse, holocaust-shoah

I read a talmudic source recently suggesting an 'exemption' for 'blasphemous' statements uttered in situations of extreme distress - the source for which was Talmudic, and this was articulated in the context of an experience of the Shoah - does anyone know this Talmud source that articulates this view?

Comment: Hello buberfanboy and welcome to mi.yodeya! Could you provide any more information on the context in which you heard about this exemption or the statement in question? I look forward to seeing you around the site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Talmud, in discussing Iyov ([Bava Basra 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=16b&format=pdf)), quotes Rava:

> אין אדם נתפס בשעת צערו
>   *A person is not liable* (lit. *trapped*) [*for what he says*] *during a moment of pain.*